# Shell, grep for list of patterns

Tags: shell, grep

I have two csv files a.csv and b.csv. I 'cut' one column from the a.csv file and now I want to grep for each one of the string from this column in second file b.csv.
Can someone please help me in writing a shell script for this?

Comment: Stick them in a file and use `grep -fF` and possibly also `-w`.

Comment: Is there no way without putting them in temp file?

Comment: You can use process substitution instead: `grep -fF <(cut ... a.csv) b.csv` but that's effectively just a file and means you need to run the `cut` again if you need to run the grep again for some reason.

Comment: This is what I am looking for.But when I am trying "grep -fF <(head -20 a.csv |cut -f 1) b.csv", I am getting error grep: F: No such file or directory

Comment: Oops, `-Ff`. Sorry, order matters.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks, this works. Can you please add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `-f` (and likely `-F` and possibly `-w`) flags to `grep` for this sort of task.

```
$ cut ... a.csv > tmp
$ grep -Ff tmp b.csv
```

You can do this without the temporary file on shells that support process substitution.

```
$ grep -Ff <(cut ... a.csv) b.csv
```